# cuda cpu function - gpu kernel overlap

Tags: c++11, cuda

I am having problems with concurrency in my CUDA application that I am trying to develop in order to practice CUDA. I want to share the work between GPU and CPU by using asynchronous behaviors of cudaMemecpyAsync and CUDA kernels but I cannot successfully overlap CPU execution and GPU execution.

It overlaps with Host to Device data transfer but kernel execution does not overlap. It basically waits CPU to finish and call the synchronization function then kernel starts to execute on device. I couldn't understand this behavior, aren't kernels always asynchronous to CPU thread?

My GPU is Nvidia Geforce GT 550m (Fermi Architecture with 1 Copy Engine and 1 Compute Engine).

I use CUDA 6.0 and Nsight 4.0.

Here is the code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

struct point4D 
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;
};

void heterogenous_1way_plus(point4D * h_ptrData, unsigned int h_dataSize, point4D * h_out, point4D pB, point4D pC);

bool correct_output(point4D * data, unsigned int size);
void flush_buffer(point4D * data, unsigned int size);
void initialize_input(point4D *& data, unsigned int size);
void cudaCheckError(cudaError_t cudaStatus, char* err);

// Implements cross product for 4D point on the GPU-side.
__global__ void gpu_kernel(point4D * d_ptrData, point4D * d_out, point4D pB, point4D pC)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    point4D pA = d_ptrData[index];
    point4D out; out.x = 0; out.y = 0; out.z = 0; out.w = 0;

    out.x +=  pA.y*(pB.z*pC.w - pC.z*pB.w) - pA.z*(pB.y*pC.w - pC.y*pB.w) + pA.w*(pB.y*pC.z - pC.y*pB.z);
    out.y += -pA.x*(pB.z*pC.w - pC.z*pB.w) + pA.z*(pB.x*pC.w - pC.x*pB.w) - pA.w*(pB.x*pC.z - pC.x*pB.z);
    out.z +=  pA.x*(pB.y*pC.w - pC.y*pB.w) - pA.y*(pB.x*pC.w - pC.x*pB.w) + pA.w*(pB.x*pC.y - pC.x*pB.y);
    out.w += -pA.x*(pB.y*pC.z - pC.y*pB.z) + pA.y*(pB.x*pC.z - pC.x*pB.z) - pA.z*(pB.x*pC.y - pC.x*pB.y);

   d_out[index] = out;
}

// Implements cross product for 4D point on the CPU-size.
void cpu_function(point4D * h_ptrData, unsigned int h_dataSize, point4D * h_out, point4D pB, point4D pC)
{
    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < h_dataSize; index++)
    {
        h_out[index].x = 0; h_out[index].y = 0; h_out[index].z = 0; h_out[index].w = 0;

        point4D pA = h_ptrData[index];

        h_out[index].x +=  pA.y*(pB.z*pC.w - pC.z*pB.w) - pA.z*(pB.y*pC.w - pC.y*pB.w) + pA.w*(pB.y*pC.z - pC.y*pB.z);
        h_out[index].y += -pA.x*(pB.z*pC.w - pC.z*pB.w) + pA.z*(pB.x*pC.w - pC.x*pB.w) - pA.w*(pB.x*pC.z - pC.x*pB.z);
        h_out[index].z +=  pA.x*(pB.y*pC.w - pC.y*pB.w) - pA.y*(pB.x*pC.w - pC.x*pB.w) + pA.w*(pB.x*pC.y - pC.x*pB.y);
        h_out[index].w += -pA.x*(pB.y*pC.z - pC.y*pB.z) + pA.y*(pB.x*pC.z - pC.x*pB.z) - pA.z*(pB.x*pC.y - pC.x*pB.y);
    }   
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int devID;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProps;

    printf("[%s] - Starting...\n", argv[0]);

    int device_count;
    cudaCheckError(cudaGetDeviceCount(&device_count), "Couldn't get device count!");

    if (device_count == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "gpuDeviceInit() CUDA error: no devices supporting CUDA.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    devID = 0;
    cudaCheckError(cudaSetDevice(devID), "Couldn't set device!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProps, devID), "Couldn't get Device Properties");
    printf("GPU Device %d: \"%s\" with compute capability %d.%d\n\n", devID, deviceProps.name, deviceProps.major, deviceProps.minor);

    cudaDeviceReset();

    const unsigned int DATA_SIZE = 30000000;
    bool bFinalResults = true;

    // Input Data Initialization
    point4D pointB;
    pointB.x = 1; pointB.y = 1; pointB.z = 0; pointB.w = 0;

    point4D pointC;
    pointC.x = 1; pointC.y = 1; pointC.z = 1; pointC.w = 0;

    point4D * data = (point4D*) malloc(DATA_SIZE * sizeof(point4D));
    point4D * out_points = (point4D*) malloc(DATA_SIZE * sizeof(point4D));
    initialize_input(data, DATA_SIZE);
    //

    flush_buffer(out_points, DATA_SIZE);
    cout << endl << endl;

    // 1+way
    heterogenous_1way_plus(data, DATA_SIZE, out_points, pointB, pointC);
    bFinalResults &= correct_output(out_points, DATA_SIZE); // checking correctness

    free(out_points);
    free(data);

    exit(bFinalResults ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 0;
}

void heterogenous_1way_plus(point4D * h_ptrData, unsigned int h_dataSize, point4D * h_out, point4D pB, point4D pC)
{
    cout << "1-way_plus: STARTS!!!" << endl;

    // Run the %25 of the data from CPU, rest will be executed on GPU
    unsigned int ratioPercentCPUtoGPU = 25;
    unsigned int d_dataSize = (h_dataSize * (100 - ratioPercentCPUtoGPU))/100;
    h_dataSize = (h_dataSize * ratioPercentCPUtoGPU)/100;
    size_t memorySize = d_dataSize * sizeof(point4D);

    cout << "Data Ratio Between CPU and GPU:" << (float)ratioPercentCPUtoGPU/100 << endl;
    cout << "CPU will process " << h_dataSize << " data." << endl;
    cout << "GPU will process " << d_dataSize << " data." << endl;

    // registers host memory as page-locked (required for asynch cudaMemcpyAsync)
    cudaCheckError(cudaHostRegister(h_ptrData, memorySize, cudaHostRegisterPortable), "cudaHostRegister failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaHostRegister(h_out, memorySize, cudaHostRegisterPortable), "cudaHostRegister failed!");

    // allocate device memory
    point4D * d_in = 0; point4D * d_out = 0;
    cudaCheckError(cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_in, memorySize), "cudaMalloc failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_out, memorySize), "cudaMalloc failed!");

    // set kernel launch configuration
    dim3 nThreads = dim3(1000,1);
    dim3 nBlocks = dim3(d_dataSize / nThreads.x,1);

    cout << "GPU Kernel Configuration : " << endl;
    cout << "Number of Threads :\t" << nThreads.x << "\t" << nThreads.y << "\t" << nThreads.z << endl;
    cout << "Number of Blocks :\t" << nBlocks.x << "\t" << nBlocks.y << "\t" << nBlocks.z << endl;

    // create cuda stream
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaCheckError(cudaStreamCreate(&stream), "cudaStreamCreate failed!");

    // create cuda event handles
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaCheckError(cudaEventCreate(&start), "cudaEventCreate failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaEventCreate(&stop), "cudaEventCreate failed!");

    // main thread waits for device
    cudaCheckError(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), "cudaDeviceSynchronize failed!");
    float gpu_time = 0.0f;
    cudaEventRecord(start, stream);

    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_in, h_ptrData, memorySize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);       
    gpu_kernel<<<nBlocks, nThreads, 0, stream>>>(d_in, d_out, pB, pC);
    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_out, d_out, memorySize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, stream);

    // The memory layout of CPU processing starts after GPU's.
    cpu_function(h_ptrData + d_dataSize, h_dataSize, h_out + d_dataSize, pB, pC);       

    cudaCheckError(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream), "cudaStreamSynchronize failed!");

    cudaCheckError(cudaEventElapsedTime(&gpu_time, start, stop), "cudaEventElapsedTime failed!");

    cudaCheckError(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), "cudaDeviceSynchronize failed!");

    // release resources
    cudaCheckError(cudaEventDestroy(start), "cudaEventDestroy failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaEventDestroy(stop), "cudaEventDestroy failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaHostUnregister(h_ptrData), "cudaHostUnregister failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaHostUnregister(h_out), "cudaHostUnregister failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaFree(d_in), "cudaFree failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaFree(d_out), "cudaFree failed!");
    cudaCheckError(cudaStreamDestroy(stream), "cudaStreamDestroy failed!");

    cudaDeviceReset();    

    cout << "Execution of GPU: " << gpu_time << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "1-way_plus: ENDS!!!" << endl;        
}

// Checks correctness of outputs
bool correct_output(point4D * data, unsigned int size)
{ 
    const static float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = -1;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].x != x || data[i].y != y ||
            data[i].z != y || data[i].w != w)
        {
            printf("Error! data[%d] = [%f, %f, %f, %f], ref = [%f, %f, %f, %f]\n",
            i, data[i].x, data[i].y, data[i].z, data[i].w, x, y, z, w);

            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// Refresh the output buffer
void flush_buffer(point4D * data, unsigned int size)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[i].x = 0; data[i].y = 0; data[i].z = 0; data[i].w = 0;
    }
}

// Initialize the input data to feed the system for simulation
void initialize_input(point4D *& data, unsigned int size)
{
    for(unsigned int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
    {
        point4D* d = &data[idx];
        d->x = 1;
        d->y = 0;
        d->z = 0;
        d->w = 0;
    }
}

void cudaCheckError(cudaError_t cudaStatus, char* err)
{
    if(cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, err);
        cudaDeviceReset();
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

And here is the Nsight screenshot [image: Nsight screenshot]:

Comment: I couldn't add Nsight screenshot due to my insufficient points on stackoverflow :/

Comment: I suggest you provide a complete example that someone else could copy, paste, compile, and run.  What happens if you [remove the cudaEventRecord() operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050945/concurrent-kernel-launch-example-cuda/23051377#23051377) ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thank you for your suggestion I added the complete code. And removing `cudaEventRecord()` did not solve anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting proper overlap, from what I can see on your profiler image.  I ran your code and see something similar.

In general, the critical sequence in your code is like this:

1. cudaMemcpyAsyncH2D
2. kernel call
3. cudaMemcpyAsyncD2H
4. cpu function
5. cudaStreamSynchronize

The CPU thread processes those steps in that order.  Steps 1-3 are asynchronous, meaning control is returned to the CPU thread immediately, without waiting for the underlying CUDA operation to complete.  And you desire that step 4 overlaps as much as possible with steps 1,2, and 3.

What we see is that the `cudaStreamSynchronize()` call shows up in the timeline approximately coincident with the *start* of the kernel execution.  This means that all CPU thread activity *preceding* the `cudaStreamSynchronize()` call has *completed* at that point (i.e. approximately at the point of the beginning of the actual kernel execution.)  Therefore the cpu function (step 4) that we are desiring to overlap with steps 1-3 is actually *completed* by the start of step 2 (in terms of actual CUDA execution).  Therefore you are getting full overlap of your cpu function with the first host->device memcpy operation.

So it's working as expected.  Because the `cudaStreamSynchronize()` call blocks the CPU thread until all stream activity is complete, it occupies the timeline from when it is encountered until the point at which the stream activity is complete.

The fact that the `cudaStreamSynchronize()` call is curiously coincident with the start of kernel execution, and that there is a gap in between the end of the H2D memcpy and the start of the kernel, is likely due to WDDM batching of commands.  When I profile your code under linux, I don't see the gap and exact coincidence, but otherwise the general flow is the same.  Here is what I see using the visual profiler under linux:

[image: Linux visual profiler]

Note that in the above image, the `cudaStreamSynchronize()` is actually encountered *during* the H2D memcpy operation before the kernel begins.

Responding to a question in the comments, I modified the app so the split percentage was 50 instead of 25:

```
unsigned int ratioPercentCPUtoGPU = 50;
```

here is what the new profiler output looks like:

[image: profiler output with modified split percentage]

We see that the CPU is taking more time relative to the GPU kernel call, and so the `cudaStreamSynchronize()` call is not encountered by the CPU thread until during the *D2H* memcpy operation.  We continue to see under linux that there is no fixed relationship between this point and the start of the kernel execution.  Now the CPU execution is fully overlapping the H2D memcpy, the kernel execution, and a small portion of the D2H memcpy.

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly you are saying it is due to WDDM. The question in my mind is, I sometimes get similar overlapping pattern when my cpu function complete before H2D data transfer; but when it takes longer than H2D transfer, it starts to postpone kernel execution. As far as I can see in your profiler your cpu execution ends before kernel. Can you check again by increasing `ratioPercentCPUtoGPU ` in `heterogenous_1way_plus()` function? Btw, thank you for your swift answer

Comment: You are totally right, today I checked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944429/cuda-performance-penalty-when-running-in-windows) and [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/550280/will-cudathreadsynchronize-truly-break-up-kernel-launches-to-avoid-wdm-timeout-/), I tried adding `cudaEventQuery(stop)` after `cudaEventRecord(stop, stream)` and it solved my issue.