# Why can't I use gpu to reduce the cpu occupancy rate?

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, cpu

From [cuda cpu function - gpu kernel overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542069/cuda-cpu-function-gpu-kernel-overlap?s=1|1.7623) ,I know how to execute the gpu and cpu functions concurrently. But here is another situation, the gpu and cpu functions have to execute serially, the problem is when cpu is blocking by gpu kernel executing, would the cpu process suspend? If yes, the occupancy rate of cpu should be low, right?

Below is my cuda code, quite simple, just for test

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel(float *d_data)
{
    //dead loop
    while(1)
    {
        *d_data = -1;
        *d_data = 1/(*d_data);
        *d_data = (*d_data) / (*d_data);
    }
}


int main()
{
    float *d_data;
    cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(float));
    kernel << <1, 1 >> >(d_data);
    //cpu process would be blocking here
    float data;
    cudaMemcpy(&data, d_data, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("%f\n",data);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `top` to check the occupancy rate of cpu is 100%

```
%Cpu10 : 75.1 us, 24.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

and I have confirmed that the cpu process I launch is running on Cpu10.

Am I missing something? I am very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The CPU process (thread, actually) doesn't suspend.

The `cudaMemcpy` operation after the kernel call is issued to the same cuda stream (the [default stream](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#default-stream)) so it blocks (the CPU thread) and waits for the kernel to complete.

The block inside the `cudaMemcpy` call is (by default) a CPU spin wait, not a thread yield.

In theory, [you can modify the CUDA device synchronization behavior](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g69e73c7dda3fc05306ae7c811a690fac).  However you will need to experiment with the flags to see if any options give you anything preferable to the default behavior.

If you have an idea how long the kernel will execute, you can also use a function like `sleep()` in CPU code to yield the thread for a specific period of time, then use a mechanism like [`cudaEventQuery`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1g2bf738909b4a059023537eaa29d8a5b7) to determine whether to proceed or continue waiting.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, use Async functions to launch two kernel function, which will execute on gpu, in one cpu process, will the two kernel functions run in the gpu concomitantly? Or just alternately?

Comment: That's a different question, right?  Please post different questions separately on SO.   The comments are not a place to ask new questions. Before you post it, you may want to search for questions about concurrent kernels, there are many.   You may also want to read the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) section on *asynchronous concurrent execution*.

Comment: I apologize for my inappropriate behavior. Your advice fix my problem, thank you!